# Find the return value of a PL/SQL function on remote database

Tags: database, oracle, logging, plsql

I have one Oracle XXg database running on a remote client and it's not possible to reproduce the environment for tests. Right now, there is one stored procedure that's returning an unexpected value (it's just an integer that should be zero but is returning some other number) and I want to discover which value is that.

I can edit the functions and procedures, but I can't call the function without using a big java application that I cannot debug. Is there any way to log the return value to a text file or some log on the database so I can check it after execution?

If there's not such functionality, what would be the less troublesome workaround?

Comment: What is `XXg` supposed to mean? There is `9i`, `10g` and `11g`

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a table to log the values?

```
CREATE TABLE mylog (t TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP, retval NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE yourprocedure 
AS
  myval NUMBER;

  PROCEDURE logval (myval NUMBER) AS PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mylog(retval) VALUES (myval);
    COMMIT;
  END logval;
BEGIN
  -- your normal code
  myval := 1; 
  -- log the result
  logval(myval);
END yourprocedure;
/
```

Then you can simply select the values from the table `mylog`...